# For cycle and if statement

Tags: android

guys! I am having a problem with for cycle.So i have a for() that goes through every value of third column from database(which is supposed to be in date format).I want to change the background color of an item from listview if the month of the added date is the same as the current month.The problem is there - if i use the code like this:

```
public void setItemRed(View view){

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= myDB.getLastID() ; i++){
        String date = myDB.getcol3(i);
        String day = date.substring(0 , 2);
        String month = date.substring(3 , 5);
        String currentDate = currentDate();
        String currentMonth = currentDate.substring(3 , 5);

        listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Everything works and every item gets red background.But when i add if :

```
public void setItemRed(View view){

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= myDB.getLastID() ; i++){
        String date = myDB.getcol3(i);
        String day = date.substring(0 , 2);
        String month = date.substring(3 , 5);
        String currentDate = currentDate();
        String currentMonth = currentDate.substring(3 , 5);
       if(date.length() == 10){
           if(month == currentMonth) {
               listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
           }
       }
    }

}
```

It does not work.Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try sorting out your indentation on the `if statement`.

Comment: `month == currentMonth` will always return false. Use `month.eqauals(currentMonth)` instead

Comment: Thank you mihail! Solved!But what is important is why does it return always false?

Comment: read some java basics first. And learn to do a research on you own before asking basic questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Well i am a newbie still.Anyways,Thank you!

Comment: @Goshoy I understand that, but being a newbie doesn't stop you from researching. Spend a little more time finding out the problem on your own is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever comparing two sets of string, you need to use the `.equals()` command. Simply by making `month == currentMonth` will not work and return false.

So try replacing `month == currentMonth` with `month.equals(currentMonth)`.

Hope that helps.